How to prevent fabric's PenceilBrush from drawing beyond the specified area
As shown in the figure, the picture is in the group. I draw on the picture. How can I limit the drawing range to within the picture and prohibit drawing outside the picture?enter image description here
As shown in the figure, the picture is in the group. I draw on the picture. How can I limit the drawing range to within the picture and prohibit drawing outside the picture?
